# Can SQL Server automatically read from more than one table if data spans more than one table without modifying the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called 'customer' which has too many rows & the decision was made to split the table into multiple tables by a date column called InsertedDate. The data span years 2009-2011.

I would like to put each year in its own table. So customers for 2009 go into one table called 'customer2009' and so on.

Say I have I have a query like:

```
SELECT LastName
  FROM Customer 
 WHERE InsertedDate BETWEEN '12/20/2009' 
                        AND '01/15/2010'
```

Is there a feature in SQL Server (in Enterperise edition ?) where if it gets such a query, it intelligently knows to get the data from different tables. The reason I ask is that I don't want to modify the query into: (there are hundreds of queries)

```
SELECT LastName 
  FROM Customer2009
 WHERE InsertedDate >= '12/20/2009' 
UNION
SELECT LastName 
  FROM Customer2010 
 WHERE InsertedDate <= '01/15/2010'
```

I would like to read a white paper and best practices and architecture to do this type of thing if a good resource exists.

**Addition:**

The gist of my question is I wanted to know if there's a built-in Enterprisy feature in SQL Server. Not to hack a solution manually which needs to be modified and maintained by people.

Comment: use a stored procedure that intelligently knows to get the data from different tables.

Comment: And when you're in 2012/13/14/15/etc?  Whomever made that decision should have their database privileges revoked.

Comment: @FiveTools Don't want to change current queries. I mentioned that.

Comment: @OMG What I am asking for takes care of future years too. It's all built in the system's smarts. I am inquiring about if something I want envisioning even exists.

Comment: Tony, if you have to ask for a workaround -- is it really that smart?  The design is against data model convention -- change it now, or the effort will be that much worse later on because there'll be more data to migrate.

Comment: +2 Ponies.  Glad to see this ruffles others feathers as well.

Comment: @OMG I didn't ask for a workaround. I asked if my requirement is already built into the system. Maybe it's only available in the Enterprise edition. I don't know.. that's why I asked. In another example I can come and say I want to keep some databases in sync and some guy comes up with some complicated SQL hacks. Another suggests using the built-in replication feature. Replication is what I was looking for and I didn't know it existed. Case closed.  Database vendors can add any features they like. No one says it must obey some data model convention. I chose an answer. Move on.

Comment: Your question specifically asked if there was a feature that would require less effort and/or perform better...  That's a work around.  I empathize with your situation (we all do), but the fact is the design you are working with is terrible and you will a lot of effort & grief to correct it ASAP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look into [table partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: @lazyDBA: Just go find 9 other questions I've answered! :-)

Comment: Did this improve in SQL Server 2008? How?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: [Query Processing Enhancements on Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345599.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a view:

```
create view vCustomer
as
SELECT LastName 
FROM Customer2009
WHERE InsertedDate >= '12/20/2009' 
UNION
SELECT LastName 
FROM Customer2010 
WHERE InsertedDate <= '01/15/2010'
```

Of course you would still need to update your stored procs, but it would be a little easier.

```
SELECT LastName
FROM vCustomer 
WHERE InsertedDate BETWEEN '12/20/2009' AND '01/15/2010'
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking for an "Enterprise" feature that does it all automatically

Comment: You want an automatic workaround that requires no changes? Is there anything you ***are*** you willing to do in order to make your ill-advised design change work?

Answer (score 0):

May be `view` - is solution? why not if so?

Comment: Why? just create several tables, for example, 10-20 years+, and be happy!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option (provided your sticking with this somewhat strange architecture) is bulding a view that looks at all those tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_all_customers AS
SELECT * FROM Customer2009
UNION
SELECT * FROM Customer2010
...
;
```

This view gives you the power to do stuff like this:

```
SELECT LastName
FROM vw_all_customers
WHERE InsertedDate >= '12/20/2009' 
AND InsertedDate <= '01/15/2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider two options : built-in partition functions (as proposed by **Joe Stefanelli**) and manual partitioning which involves creating partitioned view.  Partitioned views have some restrictions, but they also give you a possibility to use additional hardware resources, for example splitting data between different instances of SQL Server. You can find some useful info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019.aspx)